# EXCEL: Fill blank cells with above value divided by number of blanks

Tags: excel

I'm trying to convert a price paid for a package into an average price per item.
Picture included.

[image: Excel example image]

In the picture, you can see 11 total items. The first bundle was $13, and paid for the first 7. The next bundle (of 4) was also 13 dollars for those 4. The last bundle was $11 for only 1 item.
Columns A and B is the data given, column C is "Fill all blanks with above values", and column D is what it's supposed to end up being.

If I were able to make a range from "Goober" to "th", I could use =COUNTBLANK(range)+1 to find the number 7 and then apply that number to the range in a new column E. Then it's C divided by E and we're set.

The struggle is finding how to find how many blanks before you get to the next number.

Comment: Not sure you can do it with formulas... but if you want to do it in VBA check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40945455/excel-vba-count-number-of-blank-cells-below-each-non-empty-cells

Answer (score 0):

Update: I found a way to do this. With a few helper columns.

Step 1: Create a helper column that adds a number after the last blank. "IF ( ISBLANK(A30),1,B30"

This will recreate the original price column but add a "1" (or any arbitrary number) after the last data entry.

Step 2: Use =IF(ISBLANK(C2),"",IF(ISBLANK(D2),F1,D2)) To populate all blanks with the value above it.

Step 3: Use =ArrayFormula(IF(E2="","",MATCH(TRUE,E3:E1000<>"",0))), or =IF… shift+ctrl+enter on excel, to give you the number of blanks before the next value. If you don't do step 1, the last value will return #N/A instead of the number of blanks.

Step 4: Repeat Step 2 with the column from step 3.

Step 5: Using your filled in column of prices and your filled in column of # of blanks, do a simple division. Cost/number blanks

Done!